# How this Tabs tutorial works?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run this [Dynamic Tabs tutorial](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/dynamic_tabs/). After i went through the javascript, i came to know that there is no, `$("#tabs").tabs()`.

But till this time, i was using `$("#tabs").tabs()` to create tabs. But how this tutorial works. Can anyone explain me!?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: very nice link btw, thanks for sharing it

Comment: @Eric Fortis: Welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#documents a").click(function() {
    addTab($(this));
});
```

Comment: Well tabs() is a plugin which obscures a lot of code behind.  The code in the page is not a plugin, and you may think this one requires a lot more of code but not necessarily.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: The jquery code, just creating HTML mark up. So, the CSS code is really making the TAB experience, am i right!!???

Comment: It will always be a combination of both, but overall you're right